# WCF - how to make custom errors?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I've got a WCF REST project and I want to catch the errors that the WCF framework throws and display them in my way (JSON, that is).

For example, If I'm expecting an int parameter in my call and I get a string, the framework would display a page with "request error" and some trace info... I'd just like to get the exception and display it in my JSON format as response to the user.

Just to make this more clear - I'm not looking to catch an exception IN CODE, but an exception that happens outside of the code. an exception that the WCF would generate it self, such as (when I passed a string into an int field)

> The server encountered an error processing the request. Please see the service help page for constructing valid requests to the service. The exception message is 'Input string was not in a correct format.'. See server logs for more details. The exception stack trace is:...

Any ideas how this can be done?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't get it... are you asking how to catch an exception, or how to show a "pretty" error page in ASP? Please tag your question better.

Comment: You're right. I've added a little bit more explanation

Comment: Exceptions get passed through WCF... if you throw an exception in your WCF service, you can catch it in your client code. I still don't understand what the issue here is.

Comment: This is not an exception I throw. It's an exception that WCF throws (error in parameter for example) - and I want to catch it and return my own result, and not the default WCF error it returns (before it even gets to my code so I could catch it)

Comment: You should be doing your own validation or try/catch in your service method so that you can control exactly what exceptions are being thrown (if any), and then you can code your client correctly. -- That, or you could wrap your WCF call in your client with a try/catch and print out a generic, "pretty" error message. But it sounds like you aren't doing some validation or something else that you should be doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use FaultContracts to generate your own custom errors. Takes a bit of time to setup but once you have it, it works wonders. The good thing about it is that the FaultContract is completely serializable.

```
[OperationContract]
[FaultContract(typeof(CustomFault))]
string WillThrowArgumentException();
```

Here is a really good explanation of getting it to work.
http://blog.ngommans.ca/index.php?/archives/33-Handling-custom-errors-in-WCF.html

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're looking to implement global error handling in the WCF service, so you can catch unhandled exceptions (either an unanticipated error in your code or something outside your control).  If my understanding is correct, you'll want to look into the [IErrorHandler Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.ierrorhandler.aspx).

There's a number of blog posts and articles on how to impement IErrorHandler.  Here's one that covers both SOAP and REST:  [WCF Exception Handling with IErrorHandler](http://blog.wadolabs.com/2009/03/wcf-exception-handling-with-ierrorhandler/).

Comment: Thank you - I will get to it :) You've really helped!